# Powershell exclude directory from the process

Tags: powershell, command-line

Im really new in Power Shell scripting. I already have this code. And this is working, but I want to exclude the path from $exclude variable so it will not be included to the process in running process.exe. Is it possible to exclude the path? Thank you in advance!

```
$exclude = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\SCRIPTS\tester\TESTALL\excludethisfolder\' -Recurse  | Where-Object{!($_.PSIsContainer)}
$Allfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\SCRIPTS\tester\processthisfolder\" -Recurse | where{!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -gt $oldday } | Select-Object FullName

foreach ($file in $Allfiles) #check for each file in variable $Allfiles)
        {
           $file1 = $file.Fullname
           $foldername = Get-ChildItem -Path $file.FullName
           $input = $foldername.DirectoryName
           $Mothername = Get-Item -Path $input
           $output = $Mothername.Parent.Fullname
           $output = "$output\sc"
           Write-Host "The Filename: $file1"
           Write-Host "The FolderName: $input"
           Write-Host "$output"
           Write-Host "$Excludefolder"
           $argument = "$input $output $input"
           Start-Process -FilePath "C:\SCRIPTS\process.exe" -ArgumentList $argument #execute the process
        }
        Clear-variable -Name Allfiles
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your where clause to filter out paths starting with the exclude dir:

```
$Allfiles = Get-ChildItem C:\SCRIPTS\tester\processthisfolder -Recurse |
               Where {!$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.CreationTime -gt $oldday) -and !$_.FullName.StartsWith('C:\SCRIPTS\tester\TESTALL\excludethisfolder\') } | 
               Select FullName
```

Comment: Dude! Thanks for this one! I really should've ask this one, It will not come to my mind with this logic. I really appreciated it!